# How can I add space between form fields

Tags: html, css, forms

I am new to coding and designing with CSS, I am having difficulty adding space between form fields. I tried padding as well as margin attribute but still the space is not being add. Any help or recommendation on how could i add the space.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXrZp.png)

This is the code i have for form

```html
      <br>
            <label for="fname">First Name       
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="John" required>
            </label>
            
            <br>
            <label for="lname">Last Name
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lewis" required>
            </label>
                
            <br>
            <label for="email">Email
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@example.com" required>
            </label>
                
            <br>
            <label for="phone-no">Phone Number
            <input type="number" name="phone-no">
            </label>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to check out https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/

Comment: classic way to pile them is : `<p><label for="fname">First Name</label><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="John" required></p>` from there, margin or padding on p will do it can help also to align them if needed, in fact it gives you much more and easier possibilities of styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap each input field with a block level element e.g `<div>` then give the **div** some styling to set the position the way you like.